# New at C and working with directories: Trouble opening files within subdirectories

Tags: c, directory

I'm working with directories for the first time and am running into some difficulties. I wrote the following function to explore a directory, display the filesizes and permissions, then recurse on any subdirectories.

```
void exploreDIR (DIR* dir, char cwd[], int tab)
{

    struct dirent* ent;

    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {

        if(strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)
             continue;

        int i;
        i = 0;
        while(i < tab)
        {
            printf("    ");
            i = i + 1;
        }

        printf("%s ", ent->d_name);
        FILE *file = fopen(ent->d_name, "r");

        int filesize;

        if(file==NULL)
        {
            printf("[ Could not open! ]\n");
            continue; 
        }              

        struct stat st;
        stat(ent->d_name, &st);
        filesize = st.st_size;                                       

        if (st.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
        {
            printf ("(subdirectory) [");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("(%d bytes) [", filesize);
        }

        printf( (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
        printf("]\n");

        fclose(file);

        if (st.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
        {
             char tempwd[1024];
             strcpy(tempwd, cwd);
             strcat(tempwd, "/");
             strcat(tempwd, ent->d_name);
             DIR* tempdir;
             if ((tempdir = opendir (tempwd)) != NULL)
             {
                 printf("%s", tempwd);
                 exploreDIR(tempdir, tempwd, tab + 1);               
             }

         }
    }
    closedir(dir); 
}
```

However the fopen function always returns null when the function recurses on subdirectories. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. For reference, this is the main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    printf("\n");

    DIR* dir;   
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
    {
        if ((dir = opendir (cwd)) != NULL)
        {
            exploreDIR(dir, cwd, 0);               
        }
    }    

    printf("\n");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I am also somewhat concerned with my methodology. Is strcat() really the best way to explore subdirectories?

Thanks

Comment: pre-pend the directory name to the file name for the whole path in `open`.  ent->d_name is just the file name, the open has no idea what directory you are in.

Comment: The fopen() is just using the local name. I think you need to keep track of the directories you have descended and use a relative path name from you started. But I just glanced at the code.

Comment: And also in `stat()`. Why are you opening the file, anyway? You never do anything with that.

Comment: @CharlieBurns He does keep track of it, it's in the `cwd` argument. He just needs to concatenate `ent->d_name` to it.

Comment: Another option is to use chdir() as you descend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a sub-directory `./snails`, you read file names from the directory with `readdir()` such as `chewy-snails`, but to `stat()` the files, you need to prefix the name with the sub-directory name: `./snails/chewy-snails`.

The alternative, not to be undertaken lightly, is to consider using `chdir()` or (better) `fchdir()` to change directory to the relevant sub-directory. You can then `stat()` the names from `readdir()` without messing with the strings.  However, getting back to where you start is a problem — especially if you follow a symlink to get there.  This is where [`fchdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html) scores.

If you're on a system with the necessary support, the `*at()` functions may help ([`fstatat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html) etc).

But the simplest solution is to not change directories and to prefix file names with the sub-directory name before trying to use [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) or 
[`lstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html) — that's 3 links to the same content.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be putting your `cwd` variable to use. You should be putting that at the start of each filename.

Also I like using snprintf instead of strcat for building names. It will limit itself to the buffer size that you pass it, so there is no risk of overflow.